# Character spacing in textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a style to define the character spacing into a text box.

For example I have this text:

```
Hello World!
```

And I want it displayed something like:

```
H e l l o  W o r d !
```

And I need this done from a style.

I tried using [Glyph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.glyphs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and Typography but no luck!

Maybe the space between letters to be defined as pixels or something similar not necessarily a space from keyboard.

Regards.

Answer (score -2):

have you tried letter-spacing property of css styles?
For example you can create css class:

```
.letter10Spacing
{
letter-spacing:3px;
}
```

Comment: Can you add css styles to wpf elements?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought we are talking about css...

Comment: Yeah. Always helps to read the question. Helsp to give right answers.